# Get or Create functions/methods

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a standardized way to write `get_or_create` methods. For example, to create a new customer:

```
get_or_create_customer(email='hello@example.com')
```

I've seen methods like this either return `None`, return the `<item>`, or return a tuple that says whether the item was created or not in addition to the item (like django's get_or_create), `(True, <item>)`.

is there a suggested practice of what to return in a `get_or_create` method?

Comment: I would suggest not to copy this pattern at all.  It's annoying and unpythonic, even in Django.

Comment: @wim could you please clarify why you wouldn't follow the above approach? Actually perhaps an answer showing why it wouldn't be a good idea to do the above would be the most helpful of all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your example, my approach would be:

```
#Returns a tuple where the first item is "False" if the email already exists in database, 
#and "True" if it doesn't and it was appended to the database. The second item is the email.

def get_or_create_customer (email , database): #email as String, database as list
    if email in database:
        return (False, email)
    else:
        database.append(email)
        return (True, email)
```

Test code:

```
database = ["hello@gmail.com"]

print (get_or_create_customer("hello@gmail.com", database), database)
>> (False, 'hello@gmail.com') ['hello@gmail.com']

print (get_or_create_customer("example@gmail.com", database), database)
>> (True, 'example@gmail.com') ['hello@gmail.com', 'example@gmail.com']
```

Comment: Note that Django does it the *other* way (obj, created).